# 1D batched FFTs of real arrays

Tags: cuda, fft, fftw, cufft

I have heard/read that we can use the batch mode of cuFFT if we have some ***n*** FFTs to perform of some ***m*** vectors each. So to test it, I made a sample program and ran it. The data I used was a file with some `1024` floating-point numbers as the same `1024` numbers repeated `10` times. While I should get the same result for `1024` point FFT, I am not getting that. Please correct me if I am conceptually wrong somewhere and below is the code, if you can rectify some error I've made.

Note: I am working with 1D FFT only.

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NX 1024
#define DATASIZE 1024
#define BATCH 10

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        cufftHandle plan;
        cufftComplex *deviceOutputData, *hostOutputData;
        cufftReal *hostInputData, *deviceInputData;
        int i,j;

        FILE *in; // *out, *fp;

        cudaMalloc ((void**)&deviceInputData, NX*BATCH*sizeof(cufftReal));
        hostInputData = (cufftReal*) malloc (NX*BATCH*sizeof(cufftReal));

        cudaMalloc ((void**)&deviceOutputData, NX*BATCH*sizeof(cufftComplex));
        hostOutputData = (cufftComplex*) malloc (NX*BATCH*sizeof(cufftComplex));

        in = fopen ("InFile.txt", "r");

        if (in==NULL)
        {       fprintf (stderr, "Input file has some issues. Please check."); exit(1);}

        float data;
        //Allocate data

 for (i=0; i<BATCH; i++){
                for (j=0; j<DATASIZE;j++)
                {
                        fscanf(in, "%f", &data);
                        hostInputData [j + i*DATASIZE] = data;
                }
        }
        fclose (in);
        cudaMemcpy (deviceInputData, hostInputData, DATASIZE*BATCH*sizeof(cufftReal), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cufftPlan1d (&plan, NX, CUFFT_R2C, BATCH);
        cufftExecR2C (plan,  deviceInputData, deviceOutputData);
        cudaThreadSynchronize();
        cudaMemcpy (hostOutputData, deviceOutputData, DATASIZE*BATCH*sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cufftDestroy (plan);
        cudaFree (deviceOutputData);
        cudaFree (deviceInputData);

        #define a hostOutputData[j+i*NX].x
        #define b hostOutputData[j+i*NX].y
        float result[NX];
        for (i=0; i<BATCH; i++){
                printf ("\n*New Batch*\n");
                for (j=0; j<=NX/2;j++){
                        result[j] = sqrt ((a*a)+(b*b));
                        printf ("%f\n", result[j]);
                }

                for (j=1; j<NX/2; j++){
                        result[j+(NX/2)] = result [(NX/2)-j];
                        printf ("%f\n", result[j+(NX/2)]);
                }
        }
```

Comment: You should provide a complete code when asking for debug assistance.  You should also use proper error checking, both CUDA and CUFFT, and report if any errors occur, when asking for assistance.  Finally, batch mode in `cufftPlan1d` [is deprecated](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftplan1d).  You should use `cufftPlanMany` and @JackOLantern has provided a fully worked example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953171/batched-ffts-using-cufftplanmany).  This question could be marked as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Hello @RobertCrovella Sir, I inserted part of the code because I thought that that part was enough for interpretation; anyways, I have corrected the code snippet. Thanks for recommending me to Jack's code :)

Comment: Able to execute batch mode with the hlep of cudaPlanMany(). Thanks @RobertCrovella.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by Robert Crovella, and as reported in the cuFFT User Guide - CUDA 6.5,

> Batch sizes other than 1 for `cufftPlan1d()` have been deprecated. Use `cufftPlanMany()` for multiple batch execution.

Below, I'm reporting a fully worked example correcting your code and using `cufftPlanMany()` instead of `cufftPlan1d()`. As you will see,

```
int rank = 1;                           // --- 1D FFTs
int n[] = { DATASIZE };                 // --- Size of the Fourier transform
int istride = 1, ostride = 1;           // --- Distance between two successive input/output elements
int idist = DATASIZE, odist = (DATASIZE / 2 + 1); // --- Distance between batches
int inembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Input size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
int onembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Output size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
int batch = BATCH;                      // --- Number of batched executions
cufftPlanMany(&handle, rank, n, 
              inembed, istride, idist,
              onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_R2C, batch);
```

is totally equivalent to the "old fashioned"

```
cufftPlan1d(&handle, DATASIZE, CUFFT_R2C, BATCH);
```

Be warned that your example does not account for the fact that the 1D FFT of a `cufftReal` array of length `DATASIZE` is a `cufftComplex` array of `DATASIZE/2 + 1` elements.

Here is the full example:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DATASIZE 8
#define BATCH 2

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main ()
{
    // --- Host side input data allocation and initialization
    cufftReal *hostInputData = (cufftReal*)malloc(DATASIZE*BATCH*sizeof(cufftReal));
    for (int i=0; i<BATCH; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<DATASIZE; j++) hostInputData[i*DATASIZE + j] = (cufftReal)(i + 1);

    // --- Device side input data allocation and initialization
    cufftReal *deviceInputData; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceInputData, DATASIZE * BATCH * sizeof(cufftReal)));
    cudaMemcpy(deviceInputData, hostInputData, DATASIZE * BATCH * sizeof(cufftReal), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // --- Host side output data allocation
    cufftComplex *hostOutputData = (cufftComplex*)malloc((DATASIZE / 2 + 1) * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex));

    // --- Device side output data allocation
    cufftComplex *deviceOutputData; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceOutputData, (DATASIZE / 2 + 1) * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex)));

    // --- Batched 1D FFTs
    cufftHandle handle;
    int rank = 1;                           // --- 1D FFTs
    int n[] = { DATASIZE };                 // --- Size of the Fourier transform
    int istride = 1, ostride = 1;           // --- Distance between two successive input/output elements
    int idist = DATASIZE, odist = (DATASIZE / 2 + 1); // --- Distance between batches
    int inembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Input size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
    int onembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Output size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
    int batch = BATCH;                      // --- Number of batched executions
    cufftPlanMany(&handle, rank, n, 
                  inembed, istride, idist,
                  onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_R2C, batch);

    //cufftPlan1d(&handle, DATASIZE, CUFFT_R2C, BATCH);
    cufftExecR2C(handle,  deviceInputData, deviceOutputData);

    // --- Device->Host copy of the results
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(hostOutputData, deviceOutputData, (DATASIZE / 2 + 1) * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i=0; i<BATCH; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<(DATASIZE / 2 + 1); j++)
            printf("%i %i %f %f\n", i, j, hostOutputData[i*(DATASIZE / 2 + 1) + j].x, hostOutputData[i*(DATASIZE / 2 + 1) + j].y);

    cufftDestroy(handle);
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(deviceOutputData));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(deviceInputData));

}
```

Please, add your own cuFFT error checking according to [CUFFT error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267149/cufft-error-handling).

Comment: Regarding your comment that inembed and onembed are ignored for 1D pitched arrays: my results confirm this.  I spent hours trying all possibilities to get a batched 1D transform of a pitched array to work, and it truly does seem to ignore the pitch.  Has anyone gotten pitched arrays to work for 1D batched transforms?