# Cuda: least square solving , poor in speed

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, cublas

Recently ,I use Cuda to write an algorithm called 'orthogonal matching pursuit' .  In my ugly Cuda code the entire iteration takes 60 sec , and Eigen lib takes just 3 sec...

In my code Matrix A is [640,1024] and y is [640,1] ,  in each step I select some vectors from A to compose a new Matrix called A_temp [640,itera],  iter=1:500 .  I new a array MaxDex_Host[] in cpu to tell which column to select .

I want to get x_temp[itera,1] from A_temp*x_temp=y using least-square , I use a cula API  'culaDeviceSgels' and cublas matrix-vector multiplication API.

So the culaDeviceSgels would call 500 times , and I think this would be faster than Eigen lib's QR.Sovler .

I check the Nisight performence anlysis , I found the custreamdestory takes a long time . I initial cublas before iteration and destory it after I get the result . So I want to know the what is the custreamdestory , different with cublasdestory?

The main problem is memcpy and function 'gemm_kernel1x1val' . I think this function is from 'culaDeviceSgels'

while(itera<500): I use cublasSgemv and cublasIsamax to get MaxDex_Host[itera] , then

```
        MaxDex_Host[itera]=pos;
    itera++; 
    float* A_temp_cpu=new float[M*itera]; // matrix all in col-major
    for (int j=0;j<itera;j++) // to  get A_temp [M,itera] , the MaxDex_Host[] shows the positon of which column of A to chose , 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<M;i++) //M=640 , and A is 640*1024 ,itera is add 1 each step
        {
            A_temp_cpu[j*M+i]=A[MaxDex_Host[j]*M+i];
        }
    }
          // I must allocate one more array because culaDeviceSgels will decompose the one input Array ,  and I want to use A_temp after least-square solving.
    float* A_temp_gpu;
    float* A_temp2_gpu;  
    cudaMalloc((void**)&A_temp_gpu,Size_float*M*itera);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&A_temp2_gpu,Size_float*M*itera);
    cudaMemcpy(A_temp_gpu,A_temp_cpu,Size_float*M*itera,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(A_temp2_gpu,A_temp_gpu,Size_float*M*itera,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
    culaDeviceSgels('N',M,itera,1,A_temp_gpu,M,y_Gpu_temp,M);// the x_temp I want is in y_Gpu_temp's return value ,  stored in the y_Gpu_temp[0]——y_Gpu_temp[itera-1]
     float* x_temp;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&x_temp,Size_float*itera);
    cudaMemcpy(x_temp,y_Gpu_temp,Size_float*itera,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Cuda's memory manage seems too complex ,  is there any other convenience method to solve least-square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `custreamdestory` and `gemm_kernel1x1val` are internally called by the APIs you are using, so there is not much to do with them.

To improve your code, I would suggest to do the following.

1. You can get rid of `A_temp_cpu` by keeping a device copy of the matrix `A`. Then you can copy the rows of `A` into the rows of `A_temp_gpu` and `A_temp2_gpu` by a kernel assignment. This would avoid performing the first two `cudaMemcpy`s.
2. You can preallocate `A_temp_gpu` and `A_temp2_gpu` outside the `while` loop by using the maximum possible value of `itera` instead of `itera`. This will avoid the first two `cudaMalloc`s inside the loop. The same applies to `x_temp`.
3. As long as I know, `culaDeviceSgels` solves a linear system of equations. I think you can do the same also by using cuBLAS APIs only. For example, you can perform an LU factorization first by `cublasDgetrfBatched()` and then use `cublasStrsv()` two times to solve the two arising linear systems. You may wish to see if this solution leads to a faster algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. MaxDex_Host array is on the host . If I want a kernel assignment to copy rows of A to A_temp , should I allocate MaxDex_Host array to device?

Comment: Yes, you should move `MaxDex_Host` array to the device to be able to perform the row permutations you need.

Comment: I get 1.5 sec total computing time finally , thank you

Comment: Oh, if I want to copy entire gpu array to another gpu array ,  to use  cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice or write a kernel?

Comment: @Zziggurats I would say a kernel. `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` can be expensive and an assignment kernel can be preferable, see [CUDA Device To Device transfer expensive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063619/cuda-device-to-device-transfer-expensive)