# CUDA device memory copies: cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice vs copy kernel

Tags: c, cuda

I am writing a cuda kernel to copy an array to another. Both of them are in GPU memory.  I don't want to use `cudamemcpyDeviceToDevice` because of its poor performance.

The naive kernel:

```
__global__ void GpuCopy( float* des , float* __restrict__ sour ,const int M , const int N )
{
    int tx=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if(tx<N*M)
        des[tx]=sour[tx];
}
```

I think the naive kernel will not get high performance, so I try to use `__shared__` memory but it looks not good:

```
__shared__ float TILE[tile];
int tid=threadIdx.x;
for(int i=0; i<M*N/tile;i++)
{
    TILE[tid]=sour[i*tile+tid]
    des[i*tile+tid]=TILE[tid]
}
```

The former code snippet copies global memory to `des[]`, while the latter copies global memory to `__shared__` and then copies `__shared__` to `des[]`. I think that the latter is slower than the former.

So, how to write a `__shared__` code to copy memory? Another question is if I want to use `__const__` memory and the array (which is already in GPU) is larger than constant memory,  how to copy it to anther GPU memory with `__const__`?

Comment: Why to you think `cudamemcpyDeviceToDevice` has poor performance?

Comment: comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284533/cuda-least-square-solving-poor-in-speed

Comment: I don't think you need shared memory. You have to copy two arrays elementwise and there is no thread cooperation in your first kernel.

Comment: So the first kernel is enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ordinary linear-to-linear memory copying, shared memory won't give you any benefit.  Your naive kernel should be fine.  There may be some small optimizations that could be made in terms of running with a smaller number of threadblocks, but tuning this will be dependent on your specific GPU, to some degree.

Shared memory can be used to good effect in kernels that do some kind of modified copying, such as a transpose operation.  In these cases, the cost of the trip through shared memory is offset by the improved coalescing performance.  But with your naive kernel, both reads and writes should coalesce.

For a single large copy operation, `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` should give very good performance, as the overhead of the single call is amortized over the entire data movement.  Perhaps you should time the two approaches -- it's easy to do with `nvprof`.  The discussions referenced in the comments refer to a specific use-case where matrix quadrants are being swapped.  In that case, an NxN matrix requires ~1.5N `cudaMemcpy` operations, but is being compared to a single kernel call.  In that case, the overhead of the API call setup will start to become a significant factor.  However, when comparing a single `cudaMemcpy` operation to a single equivalent kernel call, the `cudaMemcpy` operation should be fast.

`__constant__` memory cannot be modified by device code, so you will have to use a host code based on `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` and `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`.

Answer (score 7):

Robert Crovella has already answered to this question. I'm here just providing a sample code to compare two approaches for memory copies from device to device in CUDA:

1. using `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice`;
2. using a copy kernel.

**THE CODE**

The test code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE   512

/***************/
/* COPY KERNEL */
/***************/
__global__ void copyKernel(const double * __restrict__ d_in, double * __restrict__ d_out, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid >= N) return;

    d_out[tid] = d_in[tid];

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 1000000;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    double *h_test = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) h_test[k] = 1.;

    double *d_in;   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_in, N * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_test, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    double *d_out; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_out, N * sizeof(double)));

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_out, d_in, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
    printf("cudaMemcpy timing = %f [ms]\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    copyKernel << <iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE >> >(d_in, d_out, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    printf("Copy kernel timing = %f [ms]\n", timerGPU.GetCounter());

    return 0;
}
```

The `Utilities.cu` and `Utilities.cuh` files are maintained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/CUDA-Utilities), while the 
The `TimingGPU.cu` and `TimingGPU.cuh` are maintained [here](https://github.com/OrangeOwlSolutions/Timing).

**THE TIMING**

Tests performed on a GeForce GTX960 card. Timings are in ms.

```
N           cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice           copy kernel
1000        0.0075                             0.029
10000       0.0078                             0.072
100000      0.019                              0.068
1000000     0.20                               0.22
```

The results confirm Robert Crovella's conjecture: `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` is generally preferable over a copy kernel.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define CHECK_CUDA(cond) check_cuda(cond, __LINE__)

void check_cuda(cudaError_t status, std::size_t line)
{
    if(status != cudaSuccess)
    {
        std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(status) << '\n';
        std::cout << "Line: " << line << '\n';
        throw 0;
    }
}

__global__ void copy_kernel(float* __restrict__ output, const float* __restrict__ input, int N)
{
    for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  i < N; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) 
        output[i] = input[i];
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int num_trials = 100;
    std::vector<int> test_sizes = { 100'000, 1'000'000, 10'000'000, 100'000'000, 250'000'000 };

    int grid_size = 0, block_size = 0;
    CHECK_CUDA(cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&grid_size, &block_size, copy_kernel, 0));

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << std::endl;

    for (auto sz : test_sizes)
    {
        std::cout << "Test Size: " << sz << '\n';

        float *d_vector_src = nullptr, *d_vector_dest = nullptr;
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc(&d_vector_src, sz * sizeof(float)));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaMalloc(&d_vector_dest, sz * sizeof(float)));

        cudaEvent_t start, stop;
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventCreate(&start));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventCreate(&stop));

        float accumulate = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_trials; i++)
        {
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventRecord(start));
            copy_kernel<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(d_vector_dest, d_vector_src, sz);
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventRecord(stop));
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));

            float current_time = 0;
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventElapsedTime(&current_time, start, stop));
            accumulate += current_time;
        }
        std::cout << "\tKernel Copy Time: " << accumulate / num_trials << "ms\n";

        accumulate = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_trials; i++)
        {
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventRecord(start));
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaMemcpy(d_vector_dest, d_vector_src, sz * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventRecord(stop));
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventSynchronize(stop));

            float current_time = 0;
            CHECK_CUDA(cudaEventElapsedTime(&current_time, start, stop));
            accumulate += current_time;
        }
        std::cout << "\tMemcpy Time: " << accumulate / num_trials << "ms\n";

        CHECK_CUDA(cudaFree(d_vector_src));
        CHECK_CUDA(cudaFree(d_vector_dest));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**GTX 1050 Mobile**

```
Test Size: 100000
        Kernel Copy Time: 0.0118ms
        Memcpy Time: 0.0127ms
Test Size: 1000000
        Kernel Copy Time: 0.0891ms
        Memcpy Time: 0.0899ms
Test Size: 10000000
        Kernel Copy Time: 0.8697ms
        Memcpy Time: 0.8261ms
Test Size: 100000000
        Kernel Copy Time: 8.8871ms
        Memcpy Time: 8.2401ms
Test Size: 250000000
        Kernel Copy Time: 22.3060ms
        Memcpy Time: 20.5419ms
```

**GTX 1080 Ti**

```
Test Size: 100000
    Kernel Copy Time: 0.0166ms
    Memcpy Time: 0.0188ms
Test Size: 1000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 0.0580ms
    Memcpy Time: 0.0727ms
Test Size: 10000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 0.4674ms
    Memcpy Time: 0.5047ms
Test Size: 100000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 4.7992ms
    Memcpy Time: 3.7722ms
Test Size: 250000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 7.2485ms
    Memcpy Time: 5.5863ms
Test Size: 1000000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 31.5570ms
    Memcpy Time: 22.3184ms
```

**RTX 2080 Ti**

```
Test Size: 100000
    Kernel Copy Time: 0.0048ms
    Memcpy Time: 0.0054ms
Test Size: 1000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 0.0193ms
    Memcpy Time: 0.0220ms
Test Size: 10000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 0.1578ms
    Memcpy Time: 0.1537ms
Test Size: 100000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 2.1156ms
    Memcpy Time: 1.5006ms
Test Size: 250000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 5.5195ms
    Memcpy Time: 3.7424ms
Test Size: 1000000000
    Kernel Copy Time: 23.2106ms
    Memcpy Time: 14.9483ms
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer. I upvoted. I looked at your network profile and you have a LOT of points in physics and chemistry. I wonder if you might support my proposal to make a [Materials Modeling Stack Exchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=M2EwM2Y4N2IzOWQ5OTk0ZTliNDQyNGMwZjg2NGVhOWIyODIzOWNiZTQ3ZWZjNGE0ZjgxOWUwZDY5ZjI4MDk3NY-HFqMF39e1D2sC70PKA2uXNrAuQag7Xp36DLw_lVuq0). I've been working very hard on it but we still need more committers.